# Is Accumulo TableOperations.createTable synchronous?

Tags: java, accumulo

I'm working with Accumulo 1.6.2 and I am seeing an issue where it appears that `TableOperations.createTable` may return without an exception, but the table still isn't ready.

For example in the following code:

```java
String tableName = "foo";
TableOperations operations = connector.tableOperations();

if(!operations.exists(tableName))
{
  operations.createTable(tableName);
}

//Make a bunch of mutations that write to the table
BatchWriter batchWriter = connector.createBatchWriter(tableName, someConfig);

batchWriter.addMutations(mutations);
batchWriter.close();
```

When I run a unit test with the above code, I will sometimes get an exception indicating that table `foo` does not exist. However, the code just created table `foo`.

The only thing I can think of is that there is a window of time after `createTable()` returns where the table still might not exist.

The Javadoc doesn't explain the behavior. I also have read an early release copy of Orielly's Accumulo book and it doesn't say either.

What is the correct pattern here? I could add something like the following:

```java
//Make table    
while(!operations.exists(tableName){}
//Do stuff with table
```

However that seems like a really ugly and potentially bug prone thing to do. I'm hoping there is a better pattern here.

Comment: Turns out there was a bug in my code. I thought it was creating the table, but in some cases the function that created the table was not called. This simplified version I posted is different from my actual code. So this is synchronous and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a table should be a synchronous operation. You should not see an exception with the above example.

If you can provide the specific exception, that might hint at a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: After looking at my code again today I found a bug in the logic. In this particular case the table actually was not created. So everything seems to be working. If after running the tests I see it again I will file a bug. But at this point I think this one was a problem in my code. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Great, glad to hear. As always, please feel free to file a JIRA issue or send us a msg on the mailing lists

Comment: I'm fairly certain it was my code, but if it comes up again I will certainly file a bug.